# How to add Multiple Address space into a Azure Rm Virtual Network using JSON Templates

Tags: json, azure, azure-virtual-network

I would like to create a JSON tempalte, which creates a VNet with vnetAddressPrefixes. ie 192.168.0.0/24 and 10.0.0.0/24.

Comment: Adding an extra paramter into the addressPrefixes feild 
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix1')]",
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix2')]"

Comment: If thats post belongs to the Question please edit it and mark the json as code

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
    "name": "vnetName",
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
            "addressPrefixes": [
                "10.0.0.0/24",
                "10.0.1.0/24"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can add more to the `addressPrefixes` array